# SQL Left Outer Joins displaying Nulls

Tags: sql, join

I've done my best to search for some guidance with this issue but it seems mine is a bit specific.

I have the following SQL Query and it's such a simple join which I believe should work, however when I try to display the `'Description'` field from the joining table, it displays every record as `NULL`. I'm hoping someone might be able to give me some guidance as to where the problems may lie.

So my scenario is, a table of Sales People with their relevant details and then a Region Lookup table...

`tblSalesPerson`:

```
ID SPCode CommonName Region
1  bloggsj Joe Bloggs PCNW
2  smiths  Sally Smith PCNE
```

`tblRegionLookup`:

```
ID Region Description
----------
1  PCNW  North West
2  PCNE  North East
```

So the query I'm trying to write is.....

```
SELECT 
    sp.ID, sp.Spcode, sp.CommonName, rl.Description
FROM 
    tblSalesPerson AS sp
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    tblRegionLookup AS rl ON sp.Region = rl.Region
ORDER BY sp.CommonName asc
```

And the result should be....

```
ID SPCode CommonName Description
----------
1  bloggsj Joe Bloggs North West
2  smiths  Sally Smith North East
```

However the Description field is NULL in every field.

I have checked there are no space characters after the text, they are both varchar(10) fields and I've also rebuilt and reorganised the indexes in case they were causing a problem. The ID field on `tblSalesPerson` is the primary key and Region field on `tblRegionLookup` is primary key.

Can anyone see what I might be missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you change the outer join to a normal join and still don't get any rows, you can conclude that the values in region doesn't match. Since we have no way of seeing your data, it is impossible to give you a decent answer

Comment: I replaced the "mysql" and "sql-server" tags with "sql".  Feel free to add the database you are actually using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is:

```
SELECT sp.ID, sp.Spcode, sp.CommonName, rl.Description
FROM tblSalesPerson sp LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    tblRegionLookup rl 
    ON sp.Region = rl.Region
ORDER BY sp.CommonName asc;
```

If `rl.Description` is `NULL`, then there is no match between the tables.  The problem is that "PCNW" in the first table does not match "PCNW" in the second.  A likely cause of this are spaces in the name.  You can test this by doing:

```
    ON replace(sp.Region, ' ', '') = replace(rl.Region, ' ', '')
```

If this doesn't work, then there are likely other characters in the field, that are either invisible or do not match.

However, that is not a fix to your real problem.  The real problem is that you have a foreign key relationship, but you are not using the primary key.  If you used the numeric primary key, then this problem would not exist.

So, modify `tblSalesPerson` to have a `RegionLookupId` column, which is an integer and refers to `tblRegionLookup(id)`.

Comment: Thanks so much this was the perfect answer. I tried the replace first to see if that worked, unfortunately it didn't. However the new LookupID field using an int worked a treat.

Comment: Joining is pretty much the key reason for using key fields like this. Understanding this concept is more important in this case than the answer to the question IMHO.